# Production integrator key cannot POST to oauth/token

Tags: c#, docusignapi

My integrator key to the API was recently approved and updated to production. I am now trying to test it against the production server.

I can still POST to `https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/oauth/token` no problem.

If i change to production: `https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/oauth/token` i get the following error:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "One or both of Username and Password are invalid."
}
```

I have tried this both with my developer account, and a new trial account. Am i missing a step between demo and production with my integrator key? Thanks.

Comment: You're going to have to contact DocuSign Customer Support to have them double check that it's in Production properly.

Comment: i did send them an email so we'll see. I am able to login to the production server using my key though, it's just this endpoint that won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was a case of user error.

I was assuming that any user i would connect as runs on the main production server `www.docusign.net`, wheras for some accounts, they could be housed on other production servers, ie: `na2.docusign.net`.

The only way to know is to call GET login_information first and make sure the base URL is correct before posting to the OAuth endpoint.